# How to remove lag when entering my password from the windows 8 lock screen?

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

I don't want to disable the lock screen entirely but instead to make it so that the first key press both dismisses the lock screen and enters that key into the password box. (right now the first key dismisses the lockscreen and keyboard input for the next half-second is ignored)

Comment: It's not possible unless someone has written any 3rd party software to tamper with how windows handles the lock screen. Microsoft considers this as a security flaw for brute force macros and that is why the key press is not registered.

There are ways to achieve this but the capability is beyond the scope of superuser.com

Comment: @RichardGrant Why is this OOS?

Comment: Keyboard input is also ignored for a while even if the first screen that appears after the Windows logo is the login prompt with the password box.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to immediately start typing with the first key press, but if you go to

**Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the computer easier to see**

At the bottom of the page, check **Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)**.

You can hit a single key to immediately dismiss the lock screen image and start typing without any delay. (I usually hit spacebar, then start typing immediately after)

Edit:
In Windows 10, this setting is more easily found in:

**Ease of Access display settings**

Toggle **Show animations in Windows** off.

Comment: The setting is not saved in Windows 10. And if the user toggles the "Show animations in Windows" slider in "Display" in Windows 10, then the delay remains.

Comment: That setting in Windows 10 is the same setting. I'll update the answer to include the Windows 10 solution.